# Write to process memory in c#

Tags: c#, virtualalloc

I want to write an offset to some address of process memory, but I cannot allocate memory or change the memory address type to be "writable". so I cannot write any offset or value to my process memory. I am not sure, but I think my process memory is just readable! Please help me to solve this issue.

This is what I tried:

```
    #region dll import

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle,
      uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, 
      byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, 
      uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, 
      uint dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool VirtualProtectEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, 
      int dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);

    #endregion

    public const int
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x40,
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008,
    PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010,
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;

    internal static bool write(IntPtr whWnd)
    {
        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(whWnd, out pid);
        if (pid != 0)
        {
            IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE |
              PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
            const int
               MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000,
               MEM_RELEASE = 0x800,
               MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000;
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
              ("write string to hex offset of memLoc");
            uint lpflOldProtect;
            int bytesWritten;
            IntPtr memLoc = (IntPtr)0x001D7AB4;
            IntPtr lpRemoteBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, memLoc, 160, PAGE_READWRITE, 
              out lpflOldProtect);
            IntPtr cave = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 16, MEM_COMMIT | 
              MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            if (lpRemoteBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("can't VirtualAlloc");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("VirtualAlloc ok");
                VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, memLoc, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
                VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, memLoc, 4096, MEM_RELEASE);
                WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, memLoc, data, 16, out bytesWritten);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("can't find the windows");
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr whWnd = FindWindow(null, "the windows name");
        write( whWnd);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `0x001D7AB4` is going to be a valid address in the other process?

Comment: `0x001D7AB4` is the address of my process that i want to write on and is valid in my process.

Comment: How do you know it is valid? You do realize that most things in the process address space can be moved around? Some are even intentionally moved around (see ASLR).

Answer (score 2):

Read your code one more time. You create a var with a value and check some lines after if the value remains the same. Of course this is the same because your code does not change it.

```
IntPtr lpRemoteBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

// [...]

if (lpRemoteBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    MessageBox.Show("can't VirtualAlloc");
    return false;
}
```

I'm sure you wanted to check the var `cave` in your condition. :)

Also, to check if your question correctly alter the process memory, use a program like [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/). It allows you to view the protection of a memory region and be sure that your memory location exists.

You can also use an injection library like [MemorySharp](http://binarysharp.com/products/memorysharp/) (I'm the author) to perform what you want.

```
// Set the address to edit
var address = new IntPtr(0x001D7AB4);

// Open the process with MemorySharp
using (var m = new MemorySharp(Process.GetCurrentProcess()))
{
    // Edit the address
    m[address].WriteString("write string to hex offset of memLoc");
}
```